# After Effects CS6 not recognizing GTX 1050 Ti GPU

Tags: after-effects, adobe, nvidia

I have a laptop with **Intel i5** chipset and **GeForce GTX 1050 Ti** GPU. Due to some work related reasons I still use Adobe After Effects CS6. Right now I am facing an issue with Raytracing in AfterEffects as it doesn't recognize my GPU. The GPU option is greyed out and I couldn't select it.

Things I've tried so far :

- Updated the Optix.dll file into a newer version(4.1).
- Added GPU name in raytracing supported cards list text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the Optix.dll to Optix.1.dll version 3.9.1 worked.